# 'int' object has no attribute 'strip' error message

Tags: python, strip

This is my program and what means this error?

```
def menuAdiciona():
    nome = input("Digite o nome de quem fez o cafe: ")
    nota = int(input("Que nota recebeu: "))

    if len(nome.strip()) == 0:
        menuAdiciona()

    if len(nota.strip()) == 0:
        menuAdiciona()

    if nota < 0:
        nota = 0
```

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `strip()` on the `nota` value, which is an integer. Don't do that.

Comment: what if it is not "you" doing that??  I am getting this error from configparser (py3.5):
`File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 691, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 1009, in _read
    if line.strip().startswith(prefix):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'`
I passed no integers to it:
`
            with open("server.properties", "rb") as f:
                configfile = f.read()
            self.properties.read_file(configfile)
`

Comment: @SurestTexas then either you have found a bug or are using the API incorrectly, e.g. passing in an integer where a string was expected.

Comment: I'm definitely not passing an integer... I'm sure I may have other ways to abuse an API, so I am not going to cry "bug", although it looks that way to me.  I have given up on Py3 configparser and am going back to reading and writing them manually :(  This was the only thread I could find related to my error and I am too tired to make a new one :P

Comment: @SurestTexas: you say Python 3.5, but your traceback shows files from Python 3.4. You are also passing in string you *already read* to the `read_file` method. That method expects an iterable (like a file object) instead; use `self.properties.read_file(f)` instead of calling `f.read()` yourself. That's exactly the kind of thing I was talking about, you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: @SurestTexas: and it is an integer because you opened the file in *binary* mode, not text mode. In binary mode you get a `bytes` object, and iterating over `bytes` gives you individual integers, each in the range 0-255. So, in effect, where the method expected an iterable of string lines, you passed in an iterable of integers.

Comment: Thanks... yes it is Py3.4.. I got it mixed up with another computer.  I'm new to Py3 and the whole thing with string/binary is driving me nuts.  I know intellectually py3 is deals with unicode and such better, but I habituated myself to py2's ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a case for which you don't know whether the incoming value is a string or something else, you can deal with this using a try...except:

```
try:
    r = myVariableOfUnknownType.strip())
except AttributeError:
    # data is not a string, cannot strip
    r = myVariableOfUnknownType
```

Answer (score 0):

integer has no strip attribute... so you can make it like this...

```
if len(str(nome).strip()) == 0:
    menuAdiciona()

if len(str(nota).strip()) == 0:
    menuAdiciona()
```

Comment: Now appears that:

File "C:\Python33\Atual2.py", line 22
    if len(str(nome.strip()) == 0:


                                 
That > its on  (:)

Answer (score 0):

strip is only available for strings

if you desperately need to strip numbers try this:

`str(nome).strip()`

`str(nota).strip()`

so it turns out to be:

```
def menuAdiciona():
nome = input("Digite o nome de quem fez o cafe: ")
nota = int(input("Que nota recebeu: "))

if len(str(nome).strip()) == 0:
    menuAdiciona()

if len(str(nota).strip()) == 0:
    menuAdiciona()

if nota < 0:
    nota = 0
```

Comment: It `nota` is an `int` then `len(str(nota).strip())` can never be 0 (assuming nobody rebound the builtins str or len).

Comment: now appears that
if if len(str(nome.strip()) == 0:
and under 0 is the > error